# If a value from two sets of data match, place the adjacent value into the cell with the formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically I'm trying to organize a spreadsheet in excel that my work uses and make it easier to update every day. Each morning we update a main data set that contains everything and then update a secondary data set that contains some values from the first one, but not all of them. There are thousands of names in the primary set and a couple hundred in the secondary set and both sets change every day; the numbers in the primary set change and thus change the numbers in the secondary set, but names are also added and removed from the secondary set daily as well. Currently we copy the updated data and paste it over the Primary Set, but after that we have to manually update the Secondary Set with the new Primary Set values.

What I'm trying to do is find a formula that will check all of column B in the primary data set, compare it to column B in the secondary data set, and if any of them match take the value in column A adjacent to the matching value from the primary data set, and place this value into Column A adjacent to the matching value in column B of the secondary data set.

For instance this would be the Primary set:

```
Numbers   Names
 123       AA
 124       AB
 125       AC
 126       AD
 127       BB
 128       BC
 129       BD
 130       CC
 131       CD
 132       DD
```

And this would be the Secondary Set before it gets updated:

```
Numbers   Names
 ___       AC
 ___       BB
 ___       BC
 ___       CD
 ___       DD
```

What I want is a formula that would make the Secondary Set look like this:

```
Numbers   Names
 125       AC
 127       BB
 128       BC
 131       CD
 132       DD
```

And would update the Secondary Set automatically if the Numbers column in the Primary Set are changed. Note that both Numbers columns in both sets are both in Column A in the excel sheet and both Names columns are in column B on the same excel sheet.

I'm kind of stumped here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH in A2 on the second sheet.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

And drag/copy down.

Where Sheet1 is the name of the sheet in which the `Primary set` is found.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately both sets are in the same sheet; with the Secondary Set above the Primary Set.

Comment: Then change the two references to only the data in the primary set.  Something like $A$50:$A100 and $B$50:$B100 Respectively.  The formula order and function remains the same.

Comment: Thank you! I did what you said and it still didn't work and then I realized I forgot to change the B2 to the cell range where the secondary set's names are and now it works perfectly. I can update the primary set and the secondary set updates automatically just like I wanted. Awesome!